# fold two list in map by stream java 8

Tags: java, stream

I wanna get rid of method and fold lists in stream operation which return map, how I can do it?

```
enum Type {
 type1, type2
}

public List<String> getList(Type type){
  return Arrays.stream(values())
           .filter(some->condition)
           .filter(var -> var.equals(type))
           .sorted()
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }

// I want to move this logic into stream which is above it
public Map<Type,List<String>> getResultMap(){
 Map<Type,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(type1, getList(type1);
    map.put(type2, getList(type2);
 
    return map;
}
```

I expect method which returns map collected two list with two keys:

```
public Map<Type,List<String>> getResultMap(){
 return             // do here logic from getList + getResultMap
               
         .collect(Collectors.toMap);

}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear and show some examples?

Comment: Where are you getting `type1` and `type2` from?

Comment: @magicmn its enum with two entries

Comment: Use Enum.values() to get all the enums and then collect them into a map? `Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> getList(v)))`. I don't think removing `getList` will make your code more readable so it should probably stay.

Comment: You haven't provide sufficient information to provide a optimal solution.  You should post examples of both of your lists and  and the expected output.

Comment: @magicmn thanks, actually what I needed,  moved the logic instead of 'getList', working as expected. provide your answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear exactly what you want so I propose the following.

```
enum Type {
    TYPE1, TYPE2 // enum constants are usually upper case by convention
}
    

static class SomeClass {
    Type type;
    String someValue;
    
    public SomeClass(Type type, String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.someValue = value;
    }
    
    public String getValue() {
        return someValue;
    }
    
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s, %s}", type, someValue);
    }
}
```

Here is some arbitrary List of `SomeClass` where each instance could contain either `TYPE1` or `TYPE2`

```
List<SomeClass> list = List.of(
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE1, "A"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE2, "B"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE2, "C"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE2, "D"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE1, "E"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE1, "F"),
        new SomeClass(Type.TYPE1, "G"));
```

now just stream the list create a map keyed by type using the `groupingBy()` collector.

```
    
Map<Type, List<SomeClass>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getType));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
TYPE2=[{TYPE2, B}, {TYPE2, C}, {TYPE2, D}]
TYPE1=[{TYPE1, A}, {TYPE1, E}, {TYPE1, F}, {TYPE1, G}]
```

If you only want a specific value of the class in the map then you can do it like this.  The second Collector, maps the class to the specific type you want (in this case a String returned by getValue()).

```
Map<Type, List<String>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getType,
                Collectors.mapping(SomeClass::getValue,
                        Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
TYPE1=[A, E, F, G]
TYPE2=[B, C, D]
```

Comment: If you provide more information I can adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code.

```
// List<String> list
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
// Stream of Type, using object here as example
Map<Object, String> map = Stream.of("Type A", "Type B", "Type C").collect(
        Collectors.toMap(type -> type, type -> { 
            // getList filter or some other logics
            return list.stream().filter(y -> type.contains(y)).findFirst().orElse(null); 
}));
```